# Dynamically writing stdout from Express to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, response

I'm trying to send a series of status messages from Express to AngularJS using `GET`, as the status messages appear. I'm able to store the messages and then send them all at once, but I would like to send the messages to Angular as the stdout is created.

When i use `res.send` or `res.json` I get the  `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error, since they are calling `res.end`, but when I use `res.write` it does not actually write the data to angular until `res.end` is called.

Is there any way to get data to Angular from Node without calling `res.end`/resetting the `res headers`?

Comment: will you share some code so can help you\

Answer (score 0):

This type of error you will get when you pass statements after sending a response.

For Example:-

```
res.send("something response");
console.log("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
console.log("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
res.send("sopmething response");
```

Will result in the error you are seeing, because once the response has been sent, the following res.send will not be executed.

Note:- If you want do anything, you should do it before sending the response.

For more Detail Visit:-[error cant set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: I'm aware of why the error is occurring, but is there any way to send a response using a method that does not contain `res.end`, which `res.send` and `res.json` both do?